# dialogflow with a non US region not working

Tags: dialogflow-es

Has anyone got dialogflow working with a non-US chatbot at all.  I just seem to get invalid credentials - yet when I point at the default it works just fine.

When I run the following no matter what I do I cant get the non US version to even authenticate.

The error message is "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential"

It works fine against the default version though just the non US one it fails with

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying for weeks

````
            {

                GeneralRoutines.Routines myRoutines = new GeneralRoutines.Routines();
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
                string DialogflowAgent = builder.GetSection("DialogflowAgent").Value;
                string DialogflowProject = builder.GetSection("DialogflowProject").Value;
                string DialogflowKey = builder.GetSection("DialogflowKey").Value;
                string DialogflowEndpoint = builder.GetSection("DialogflowEndpoint").Value;
                string DialogflowRegion = builder.GetSection("DialogflowRegion").Value;

                string answer = "";

                try
                {

                    GoogleCredential googleCredential;
                    var jsonpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + DialogflowKey;
                    googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonpath);

                    var x = new SessionsClientBuilder()
                    {
                        ChannelCredentials = googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials(),
                        Endpoint = DialogflowEndpoint
                    };
                    var client = x.Build();

                    var y = new ContextsClientBuilder()
                    {
                        ChannelCredentials = googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials(),
                        Endpoint = DialogflowEndpoint
                    };
                    var contextsClient = y.Build();

                    var Session = new Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.SessionName(DialogflowProject, ToTelephoneNumber + "_" + ToRedirectedTelephoneNumber);

                    var commonContext = new global::Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.Context
                    {
                        Name = "projects/" + DialogflowProject + "/locations/" + DialogflowRegion + "/agent/sessions/" + Session.SessionId + "/contexts/" + ToRedirectedTelephoneNumber,
                        LifespanCount = 1
                    };
                    Context responses = contextsClient.CreateContext("projects/" + DialogflowProject + "/locations/" + DialogflowRegion + "/agent/sessions/" + Session.SessionId, commonContext);

                    var response = client.DetectIntent(
                        session: Session,

                        queryInput: new QueryInput()
                        {
                            Text = new TextInput()
                            {
                                Text = question,
                                LanguageCode = "en"
                            }
                        }
                    );

                    answer = response.QueryResult.FulfillmentText.ToString();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

                return answer;
            }```
````

Comment: What is the error message you encounter? Can you edit you post and include it as well?

Comment: hi,  It fails to authenticate  "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential".  The same config works well with the default location chatbot though just the non us version it fails with

Comment: Do you mean in your question that you have 2 chat bots? 1 in the US and 1 outside the US? If so, do you change the value of `DialogflowRegion` to match the region of the chat bot when running your code?

Comment: yes thats correct.  when its pointed at the default(US -  dialogflow.googleapis.com) it works fine but if I change it to point at end point europe-west2-dialogflow.googleapis.com it fails with the authentication issue.  Thank you for your help

Comment: If your 2 chat bots are in 1 project, you need to explicitly set the scope when using a regional endpoint as per [document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region#api).But if your chat bots are on separate projects, are you using the correct service account per agent?

Comment: HI,  I have two separate projects, each has a separate service account as well.  Can you define the location/region of the project or service account?

Comment: There is no location option for the service account. As long as the service account has the correct roles it should authenticate your requests. When you are using the non US bot, are using the non US bot service account at `googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonpath)` when the code runs?

Answer (score 0):

> Agent interactions through text-based and phone gateway integrations
> only use the **default language** of the agent.

from [Dialogflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-multilingual#int)

Comment: hi,  I am using the default language I dont believe this is the issue.  Thanks Steve